# Groupby with weight

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d=pd.DataFrame({'Age':[18,20,20,56,56],'Race':['A','A','A','B','B'],'Response':[3,2,5,6,2],'Weight':[0.5,0.5,0.5,1.2,1.2]})
d
    Age     Race    Response    Weight
0   18      A       3           0.5
1   20      A       2           0.5
2   20      A       5           0.5
3   56      B       6           1.2
4   56      B       2           1.2
```

I know that I can apply a group-by to get the count by age and race like this:

```
d.groupby(['Age','Race'])['Response'].count()
Age  Race
18   A       1
20   A       2
56   B       2
Name: Response, dtype: int64
```

But I'd like to use the "Weight" column to weight the cases such that the first 3 rows will count as 0.5 instead of 1 each and the last two will count as 1.2. So, if grouping by age and race, I should have the following:

```
Age  Race
18   A       0.5
20   A       1
56   B       2.4
Name: Response, dtype: int64
```

This is similar to using the "Weight Cases" option in SPSS.
I know it's possible in R and I've seen a promising library in Python (though the current build is failing) [here](https://github.com/InContextSolutions/PandaSurvey).

And PySal (not sure if it's applicable here)

...but I'm wondering if it can just be done somehow in the group-by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're just looking for [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) with the weights.

```
d.groupby(['Age', 'Race']).Weight.sum()

## Age  Race
## 18   A       0.5
## 20   A       1.0
## 56   B       2.4
## Name: Weight, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly obvious... but a fun way to do it with `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(
    [tuple(row) for row in d[['Age', 'Race']].values.tolist()]
)

pd.Series(
    np.bincount(f, d.Weight.values),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(u, names=['Age', 'Race'])
)

Age  Race
18   A       0.5
20   A       1.0
56   B       2.4
dtype: float64
```

Comment: "Not exactly obvious" might be a _slight_ understatement ;) but this is neat.